# Express Js: req.session vs cookie vs local storage vs session storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am new to Express JS and frontend. I am developing an app which is using req.session for maintaining the user session and local storage for storing some other temporary info.

I have seen various articles for differences between the above but I am still unclear which is used when and how long does each persists.

According to me:

1.req.session: The server maintains this session. This gets cleared when user clears cookies.

2.cookies: Cookies are sent to server to maintain authentication

3.local storage: This persists till user deletes the cookies?

4. session storage: This is maintained by browser and persists for one tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go through each of your points and discuss them...

> **1) req.session:** The server maintains this session. This gets cleared when user clears cookies.

If you're keeping this in a persistent store (disk-backed data store), you can keep this state for as long as you want.  The server will lose track of the client that it corresponds to when the user clears their cookies.  Depending upon how you manage your persistent user storage, you may be able to rebuild a previous session object when the user logs back in again (allowing you to use their userid to find their lasting state in your database, create a new session cookie, build a new session object from that and reconnect that browser with a new session object).

> **2) cookies:** Cookies are sent to server to maintain authentication

That's an over simplification of the utility of cookies.  Cookies allow a server to set some state in the user's browser that will be presented back to the server with each request from that specific browser.  Cookies are often used for keeping track of an authenticated client and often used for keeping a key to a server-side session object.  There are thousands of other things cookies can be used for too (user site preferences, tracking ids, other user state, etc...).

> **3) local storage:** This persists till user deletes the cookies?

Browser local storage has no connection at all with cookies.  It is a separate local data store in the browser that is accessible only to client-side Javascript in a web page.  Deleting cookies has nothing to do with deleting local storage.  They are separate items that can be separately retained or deleted.  The server has no access at all to local storage.  In addition, local storage is segmented so that the local storage values form one web site cannot be accessed by Javascript in pages from another site.

> **4) session storage:** This is maintained by browser and persists for one tab.

It's not quite clear what you mean by "session storage".  There are "session cookies" which are purposely designated upon creation to only persist while a given browser is running.  If the browser exists and then some time later is restarted, any session cookies will be gone.  Their purpose is generally for short term cookies, not meant to persist beyond what the user is currently doing.

One other possible thing you might have meant by session storage is long term, persistent storage on the server (typically in a database on disk) for various user properties or state that you want to last a long time.  Imagine the user populates a shopping cart and you want them to be able to keep that shopping cart indefinitely as they move from device to device and as they add/remove things from it over a significant amount of time.  For these types of things, you won't typically rely on a session object to keep track of these, but will use a database as the main source of that data.  It's possible some subset of data currently being worked on might be cached in a server-side session object, but that would only be for expediency, not as the long term storage for it.

Or perhaps you meant `Window.sessionStorage` in the browser.  That works like localStorage, but only persists for the duration of the browser being open (similar lifetime to session cookies) and unlike localStorage, each tab or window has its own sessionStorage.  Like localStorage, each origin has its own sessionStorage some a page from one origin can't access the sessionStorage for a page from a different origin, even if they were both loaded into the same window/tab.

---

In order to help you more specifically with your application, we would have to understand each piece of state you wanted to keep track of and what it was used for.  Only then could we suggest what mechanism might be best for storing it.

Comment: You are mixing up `session storage` with `sessions`. Both are different.

Comment: session storage refers to window's session storage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @AnchikaAgarwal - OK, that makes sense.  That's just like localStorage, but only persists while the browser is running.  When the browser shuts down, Window.sessionStorage is wiped out.   Each tab or window has its own sessionStorage.  I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

All are different type of `storage mechanisms` commonly use in `web application development`.

**But** The matter is choosing the correct one.

---

**In Short**

**`Cookie Storage`**

Cookie is a browser storage mechanism, But can access from server-side through request. Developers use cookies to store data which should be accessible from server and client.

*Example: Authentication Tokens, Analytical Data*

**`Session`**

Session storage is a server-side storage mechanism which can be only accessed by server. So we cannot access from browser directly. Use sessions to store confidential information.

Data in session will be destroyed when the session is closed.

**`Local Storage`**

Local Storage is like Cookie **BUT** we cannot access from server, we can store much more data than cookies and it doesn't expire unless we clear.

*Cookies - 4 KB & 
Local Storage - 5 MB*

**`Session Storage`**

Session Storage is similar to Local Storage. But the only difference is, Local Storage doesn't expire **But** Session storage will be destroyed when page session ends. Session storage keeps different session per page (tabs)

Answer (score 0):

**req.session**
When a user visits the site, it creates a new session object for the user and assigns them a cookie.
Whenever the user request from the same client again, the cookie is checked, sent to the server for processing and the session information stored is updated.

The difference between Cookies, Local Storage(LS) and Session Storage(SS) is as follows.

1. Cookies is processed server side, while LS and SS data is never sent to server. They are stored locally.
2. Storage capacity of a Cookie is max 4 KB, while for LS and SS is more than 5 MB.
3. Cookies mostly store only the session id. While LS and SS can store more information like user information or page browsing history.
4. SS gets cleared when a user closes tab(session ends). While Cookies can be deleted by clearing cookies and LS can be cleared by deleting Browser cache.

I will update the answer if I remembered anything else.